# Object Oriented programming on 8-bit MCU Case Study

Tags: object-oriented, embedded-systems

I see that there's a lot of questions related to OO Programming here. I'm actually trying to find a specific resource related to embedded OO approaches for an 8 bit MCU.

Several years back (maybe 6) I was looking for material related to Object Oriented programming for resource constrained 8051 microprocessors. I found an article/website with a case history of a design group that used a very small RAM part, and implemented many Object based constructs during their C design and development. I believe it was an 8051. The project was a success, and managed to stay inside the very small ROM/RAM they had available.

I'm attempting to find it again, but Google can't locate it. The article was well written, and recommended a "mixed" approach using C methods for inheritance and encapsulation - if I recall correctly.

Can anyone help me locate this article?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not referring to [Embedded C++](http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/) or [Wikipedia on Embedded C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B)

This [8051 projects forum](http://www.8051projects.net/forum-t1260-post.html) appeared to have something similar to what you were talking about.

And there, the magic search terms appear to be

```
www.engg.le.ac.uk/books/Pont/ec51.htm
www.engg.le.ac.uk/books/Pont/ec51bugs.pdf
www.le.ac.uk/engineering/mjp9/pttesguide.htm
```

The first two URLs redirect to the Leicester Engineering site.  The last one goes through.
And a google search of that reveals some hits that are also linked to from the third link.  You may be able to find the professor who owns the course and see if the pdf is available.

This is the [Professor's site](http://www.le.ac.uk/engineering/mjp9/)

Comment: As you guessed, I wasn't referring to Wikipedia. However, there's a bunch of stuff listed on the professor's website - thanks for that link. However, this might be the article I was looking for here: http://www.eetindia.co.in/STATIC/PDF/200011/EEIOL_2000NOV02_EMS_EDA_TA.pdf?SOURCES=DOWNLOAD